# Packaged Electron app (.exe) crashes silently, runs fine via command line

Tags: windows, electron

Running my Electron app via command-line works fine, but when I double-click the .exe of the packaged app, nothing happens other than my cursor doing a quick "busy" animation. I assume my app is silently crashing.

Is there a way I can get an error message or a crash report from the .exe to help me see what's going on?

From the root of my app directory, both these methods result in my app running fine:

- `node_modules\.bin\electron.cmd .`
- `electron-packager .
  node_modules\.bin\electron.cmd my_app-win32-x64\resources\app`

#### Environment

- OS: Windows 10 Anniversary x64
- Node: 4.3.1
- Npm: 1.14.12
- Local electron: 1.4.3
- Local and Global electron-packager: 8.1.0
- electron-rebuild (for native module "serialport"): 1.2.1

Comment: Run the application under a debugger, like [NTSD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx).

Comment: I have tried following [these steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bxe8ytt.aspx) to debug the .exe in Visual Studio, but the only debug output is a bunch of "Cannot find or open the PDB file.", followed by "The program '[17448] my_app.exe' has exited with code 20 (0x14)."

I have also checked the Windows Event Viewer, and there's nothing there for my Electron app.

Comment: Set up your debugger to break when an exception is thrown. This is likely an SEH (Win32) exception. You'll also want to set up to use the Microsoft symbol server. And start the application using *Debug* -> *Step Into...* ([F11] with C++ keyboard shortcuts). That will ensure that you get diagnostics from the startup process as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I enabled breaking on all possible exceptions, enabled downloading all symbols from Microsoft symbol server, and set the run log level to diagnostics. I still get the same behavior as in my 1st comment (process exits with code 20, no error or exception shown).

Comment: sounds stupid, but you checked it in other platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was not an Electron problem. This was my app trying to access a path relative to `process.cwd()`, which, when double-clicking the .exe file in the output folder, was not the expected one.

I was able to debug this by running the .exe from the command line, instead of double-clicking the .exe:
`my_app-win32-x64\my_app.exe`

This causes `console.log()` output to be visible in the command prompt, which allowed me to finally see the exception that was occurring.

Answer (score 0):

One way to debug such issues is to open a terminal or cmd and drag the exe to it or launch the exe from the terminal or cmd. this will print any uncaught error the app might be throwing.

Answer (score 0):

This can be an issue with paths if you're spawning sub processes - you can use https://github.com/jonluca/node-fix-path to fix the paths on linux and macos